# Class variable dictionary not saving with pickle.dump in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I am using pickle to save an object graph by dumping the root. When I load the root it has all the instance variables and connected object nodes. However I am saving all the nodes in a class variable of type dictionary. The class variable is full before being saved but after I unpickle the data it is empty.

Here is the class I am using:

```
class Page():

    __crawled = {}

    def __init__(self, title = '', link = '', relatedURLs = []):
        self.__title = title
        self.__link = link
        self.__relatedURLs = relatedURLs
        self.__related = [] 

    @property
    def relatedURLs(self):
        return self.__relatedURLs

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.__title

    @property
    def related(self):
        return self.__related

    @property
    def crawled(self):
        return self.__crawled

    def crawl(self,url):
        if url not in self.__crawled:
            webpage = urlopen(url).read()
            patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
            patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel="canonical" href="([^"]*)" />')
            patFinderRelated = re.compile('<li><a href="([^"]*)"')

            findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle, webpage)
            findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink, webpage)
            findPatRelated = re.findall(patFinderRelated, webpage)
            newPage = Page(findPatTitle,findPatLink,findPatRelated)
            self.__related.append(newPage)
            self.__crawled[url] = newPage
        else:
            self.__related.append(self.__crawled[url])

    def crawlRelated(self):
        for link in self.__relatedURLs:
            self.crawl(link)
```

I save it like such:

```
with open('medTwiceGraph.dat','w') as outf:
    pickle.dump(root,outf)
```

and I load it like such:

```
def loadGraph(filename): #returns root
    with open(filename,'r') as inf:
        return pickle.load(inf)

root = loadGraph('medTwiceGraph.dat')
```

All the data loads except for the class variable __crawled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be using new-style classes: `class Page(object):`.

Comment: This did not help but where can I read more about new-style objects? I just started python coming from java, so I'm not totally sure what I'm doing yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python doesn't really pickle class objects. It simply saves their names and where to find them. From the documentation of [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> Similarly, **classes are pickled by named reference**, so the same
>   restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that **none of
>   the class’s code or data is pickled**, so in the following example the
>   class attribute `attr` is not restored in the unpickling environment:
>
> ```
> class Foo:
>     attr = 'a class attr'
>
> picklestring = pickle.dumps(Foo)
> ```
>
> These restrictions are why picklable functions and classes must be
>   defined in the top level of a module.
>
> Similarly, **when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and
>   data are not pickled along with them**. Only the instance data are
>   pickled. This is done on purpose, so you can fix bugs in a class or
>   add methods to the class and still load objects that were created with
>   an earlier version of the class. If you plan to have long-lived
>   objects that will see many versions of a class, it may be worthwhile
>   to put a version number in the objects so that suitable conversions
>   can be made by the class’s `__setstate__()` method.

In your example you could fix your problems changing `__crawled` to be an instance attribute or a global variable.

Answer (score 5):

By default pickle will only use the contents of `self.__dict__` and not use `self.__class__.__dict__` which is what you think you want.

I say, "what you think you want" because unpickling an instance should not mutate class level sate.

If you want to change this behavior then look at `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, what I did was make a superclass Graph which contained an instance variable __crawled and moved my crawling functions into Graph. Page now only contains attributes describing the page and its related pages. I pickle my instance of Graph which contains all my instances of Page. Here is my code.

```
from urllib import urlopen
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pickle

###################CLASS GRAPH####################
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self,roots = [],crawled = {}):
        self.__roots = roots
        self.__crawled = crawled
    @property
    def roots(self):
        return self.__roots
    @property
    def crawled(self):
        return self.__crawled
    def crawl(self,page,url):
        if url not in self.__crawled:
            webpage = urlopen(url).read()
            patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
            patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel="canonical" href="([^"]*)" />')
            patFinderRelated = re.compile('<li><a href="([^"]*)"')

            findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle, webpage)
            findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink, webpage)
            findPatRelated = re.findall(patFinderRelated, webpage)
            newPage = Page(findPatTitle,findPatLink,findPatRelated)
            page.related.append(newPage)
            self.__crawled[url] = newPage
        else:
            page.related.append(self.__crawled[url])

    def crawlRelated(self,page):
        for link in page.relatedURLs:
            self.crawl(page,link)
    def crawlAll(self,obj,limit = 2,i = 0):
        print 'number of crawled pages:', len(self.crawled)
        i += 1
        if i > limit:
            return
        else:
            for rel in obj.related:
                print 'crawling', rel.title
                self.crawlRelated(rel)
            for rel2 in obj.related:
                self.crawlAll(rel2,limit,i)          
    def loadGraph(self,filename):
        with open(filename,'r') as inf:
            return pickle.load(inf)
    def saveGraph(self,obj,filename):
        with open(filename,'w') as outf:
            pickle.dump(obj,outf)
###################CLASS PAGE#####################
class Page(Graph):
    def __init__(self, title = '', link = '', relatedURLs = []):
        self.__title = title
        self.__link = link
        self.__relatedURLs = relatedURLs
        self.__related = []      
    @property
    def relatedURLs(self):
        return self.__relatedURLs 
    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.__title
    @property
    def related(self):
        return self.__related
####################### MAIN ######################
def main(seed):
    print 'doing some work...'
    webpage = urlopen(seed).read()

    patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
    patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel="canonical" href="([^"]*)" />')
    patFinderRelated = re.compile('<li><a href="([^"]*)"')

    findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle, webpage)
    findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink, webpage)
    findPatRelated = re.findall(patFinderRelated, webpage)

    print 'found the webpage', findPatTitle

    #root = Page(findPatTitle,findPatLink,findPatRelated)
    G = Graph([Page(findPatTitle,findPatLink,findPatRelated)])
    print 'crawling related...'
    G.crawlRelated(G.roots[0])
    G.crawlAll(G.roots[0])  
    print 'now saving...'
    G.saveGraph(G, 'medTwiceGraph.dat')
    print 'done'
    return G
#####################END MAIN######################

#'http://medtwice.com/am-i-pregnant/'
#'medTwiceGraph.dat'

#G = main('http://medtwice.com/menopause-overview/')
#print G.crawled


def loadGraph(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as inf:
        return pickle.load(inf)

G = loadGraph('MedTwiceGraph.dat')
print G.roots[0].title
print G.roots[0].related
print G.crawled

for key in G.crawled:
    print G.crawled[key].title
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `dill` can solve this problem.
`dill` package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28543378/6301132

According Asker's code, into this:

```
#notice：open the file in binary require

#save
with open('medTwiceGraph.dat','wb') as outf:
    dill.dump(root,outf)
#load
def loadGraph(filename): #returns root
    with open(filename,'rb') as inf:
        return dill.load(inf)

root = loadGraph('medTwiceGraph.dat')
```

I wrote another example:

```
#Another example (with Python 3.x)

import dill
import os

class Employee: 

    def __init__ (self ,name='',contact={}) :
        self.name = name
        self.contact = contact

    def print_self(self):
        print(self.name, self.contact)

#save
def save_employees():
    global emp
    with open('employees.dat','wb') as fh:
        dill.dump(emp,fh)

#load
def load_employees():
    global emp
    if os.path.exists('employees.dat'):
        with open('employees.dat','rb') as fh:
            emp=dill.load(fh)

#---
emp=[]
load_employees()
print('loaded:')
for tmpe in emp:
    tmpe.print_self()

e=Employee() #new employee
if len(emp)==0:
    e.name='Jack'
    e.contact={'phone':'+086-12345678'}
elif len(emp)==1:
    e.name='Jane'
    e.contact={'phone':'+01-15555555','email':'a@b.com'}
else:
    e.name='sb.'
    e.contact={'telegram':'x'}
emp.append(e)

save_employees()
```

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  First off, I agree with you -- `dill` should be able to save the object's state correctly.

However, I can't give you a +1 because your code snippet above is wrong.  It would be better to **show** that `dill` can correctly serialize the OP's object… and what you have will do nothing but throw an error.

Comment: That code snippet is just a hint, But I confess I wasn't rigorous enough. Let me complement my answer. Thanks for your reply & dill package!