# Saving Object State with Pickle (objects containing objects)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, object, pickle

I'm trying to figure out how to serialize an object with `Pickle` to a save file.  My example is an object called `World` and this object has a `list` (named `objects`) of potentially hundreds of instantiated objects of different class types.

The problem is that `Pickle` won't let me serialize the items within the `World.objects` list because they aren't instantiated as attributes of `World`.

When I attempt to serialize with:

```
with open('gsave.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(world.objects, output, pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL)
```

I get the following error:

`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'world.LargeHealthPotion'>:`
    `attribute lookup LargeHealthPotion on world failed`

So, my question is: what is an alternative way of storing the `world.objects` list items so that they are attributes of `world` rather than list items that don't get saved?

**UPDATE**
I think my issue isn't where the objects are stored; but rather that the class `LargeHealthPotion` (and many others) are dynamically created within the `World` class by operations such as this:

```
def __constructor__(self, n, cl, d, c, h, l):
    # initialize super of class type
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name=n, classtype=cl, description=d, cost=c,
                                         hp=h, level=l)
    # create the object class dynamically, utilizing __constructor__ for __init__ method
    item = type(item_name,
                (eval("{}.{}".format(name,row[1].value)),),
                {'__init__':__constructor__})
    # add new object to the global _objects object to be used throughout the world
    self._objects[item_name] = item(obj_name, obj_classtype, obj_description, obj_cost,
                                    obj_hp, obj_level)
```

When this finishes, I will have a new object like `<world.LargeHealthPotion object at 0x103690ac8>`.  I do this dynamically because I don't want to explicitly have to create hundreds of different types of classes for each different type of object in my world.  Instead, I create the class dynamically while iterating over the item name (with it's stats) that I want to create.

This introduces a problem though, because when pickling, it can't find the static reference to the class in order to deconstruct, or reconstruct the object...so it fails.

What else can I do? (Besides creating literal class references for each, and every, type of object I'm going to instantiate into my world.)

Comment: instead of creating thousands of classes you could have a dictionary of information (name, classtype, description, cost, hp, level) and then each object have an attribute that points it to correct entry in the dictionary?

Comment: you could even use `property` to do the lookup so you can still access the info the same way as class attributes.  PS: you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235078/how-to-avoid-infinite-recursion-with-super

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I don't exactly follow you about the dictionary idea.  I realize that I could store all the items in a dictionary, but I would still have to create objects to reference each of the data points for the dictionary element.  And those objects would cause the same problem with pickle, being that I had to dynamically create the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle does not pickle classes, it instead relies on references to classes which doesn't work if the class was dynamically generated. ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638436/5827215) has appropriate exert and bolding from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled))

So pickle assumes that if your object is from the class called `world.LargeHealthPotion` then it check that that name actually resolves to the class that it will be able to use when unpickling, if it doesn't then you won't be able to reinitialize the object since it doesn't know how to reference the class.  There are a few ways of getting around this:

### Define [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) to reconstruct object

I'm not sure how to demo this method to you, I'd need much more information about your setup to suggest how to implement this but I can describe it:

First you'd make a function or `classmethod` that could recreate one object based on the arguments (probably take class name, instance variables etc.) Then define `__reduce__` on the object base class that would return that function along with the arguments needed to pass to it when unpickling.

### Put the dynamic classes in the global scope

This is the quick and dirty solution.  Assuming the class names do not conflict with other things defined in the `world` module you could theoretically insert the classes into the global scope by doing `globals()[item_name] = item_type`, but I do not recommend this as long term solution since it is very bad practice.

### Don't use dynamic classes

This is definitely the way to go in my opinion, instead of using the `type` constructor, just define your own class named something like `ObjectType` that:

- Is *not* a subclass of `type` so the instances would be pickle-able.
- When an instance is it called constructs a new game-object that has a reference to the object type.

So assuming you have a class called `GameObject` that takes `cls=<ObjectType object>` you could setup the `ObjectType` class something like this:

```
class ObjectType:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.item_name = name
        self.base_item_description = description
        #other qualities common to all objects of this type

    def __call__(self, cost, level, hp):
        #other qualities that are specific to each item
        return GameObject(cls=self, cost=cost, level=level, hp=hp)
```

Here I am using the [`__call__` magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) so it uses the same notation as classes `cls(params)` to create instances, the `cls=self` would indicate to the (abstracted) `GameObject` constructor that the class (type) of `GameObject` is based on the `ObjectType` instance `self`. It doesn't have to be a keyword argument, but I'm not sure how else to make a coherent example code without knowing more about your program.

Comment: This is a great answer.  I'm not sure I fully understand the __call__ reference part, but I'll plug away at it for awhile and see if it starts making sense.  Thanks for the detailed response; and I agree, not using dynamic classes is the best way to go.

Comment: would you be able to help me understand the `__call__` reference more?  I'm not sure I understand how `__call__` gets executed, and furthermore how (in your example) `game_object` should be constructed in order to consume the `cls=self` argument.

Comment: the [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) magic method is used when an object is called, so you would call the 'ObjectType' object in the same way you'd call the dynamic class to create game objects, I figured it would reduce the amount of extra code you'd need to write to implement but I guess I should have given a bit more explanation about that in the answer...